# Eigen Tensor compilation error

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I am experimenting with `Eigen::Tensor`, and I do not manage to understand why the most basic example is failing. Why does this piece of code

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main()
{
    Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> a(4, 4);
    Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> b(4, 4);

    a.setRandom();
    b.setRandom();

    a += b;

    return 0;
}
```

results in error:

```
In file included from eigen.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:142:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorStorage.h:39:7: error: class template partial specialization is not
      more specialized than the primary template [-Winvalid-partial-specialization]
class TensorStorage<T, FixedDimensions, Options_>
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorStorage.h:34:63: note: template is declared here
template<typename T, typename Dimensions, int Options_> class TensorStorage;
```

Comment: Seems to [compile fine](https://godbolt.org/g/HoMXxp) with any recent version of Eigen.

Comment: I have tested it on the version that comes with Homebrew (3.3.4) and that comes with Ubuntu 17.10 (also 3.3.4).

Answer (score 1):

Please, update to the default branch (recommended for the Tensor module), or at least to the head of the 3.3 branch.

Comment: I use 3.3.4 that comes with Homebrew. Is that one insufficient?

Comment: 3.3.5 will be ok.